# Configuring application insights for React app

Tags: reactjs, azure-application-insights

https://www.npmjs.com/package/applicationinsights

Is there any way to configure application insights for a React application?

Answer (score 1):

There is a react-appinsights library available in the Microsoft Azure repositories on github.

It provides plenty of details on how to get started.

Comment: react-appinsights has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this one

https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-JS/tree/master/extensions/applicationinsights-react-js

It works reasonably well and is being maintained